# Extracting data from JSON column defined as String

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A table has a ports column (defined as VARCHAR) which has the following data:

> [{u'position': 1, u'macAddress': u'00:8C:FA:C1:7C:88'}, {u'position':
> 2, u'macAddress': u'00:8C:FA:5E:98:81'}]

I want to extract the data from just the macAddress fields into separate rows. I tried to flatten the data in Snowflake but it is not working as the column is not defined as VARIANT and the the fields have a 'u' in front of them (this is my guess).

```
00:8C:FA:C3:7C:84
00:5C:FA:7E:98:87
```

Could someone please help with the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided JSON is not a valid JSON but it is possible to treat it as one with text operations and `PARSE_JSON`:

```
SELECT s.value:macAddress::TEXT AS macAddress
FROM t
,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, 'u''', ''''), '''', '"'))) 
                 AS s;
```

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(col TEXT)
AS
SELECT $$[{u'position': 1, u'macAddress': u'00:8C:FA:C1:7C:88'}, {u'position': 2, u'macAddress': u'00:8C:FA:5E:98:81'}]$$;
```

Output:

[image]